# How to improve my multiclass text-classification on German text?

Tags: python, nlp, svm, text-classification, tf-idf

I am new in NLP and it is a bit confusing me.
I am trying to do a text classification with SVC on my dataset.
I have an imbalanced dataset of 6 classes.
The text is news for classes of health, sport, culture, economy, science and web.
I am using TF-IDF for vectorization.

the preprocessing steps: `lower-case` all the texts and to remove the `stop-words`. since my text is in German I did not use `lemmatization`

my first try:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
X_train = train['text']
y_train = train['category']
X_test = test['text']
y_test = test['category']

# Linear SVC:
text_clf_lsvc = Pipeline([('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()), ('clf', LinearSVC()),])
predictions = text_clf_lsvc.predict(X_test)
```

my metrci acuuracy score was: 93%

then I decided to reduce the dimensionality: so on my 2nd try I added TruncatedSVD

```
# Linear SVC:
text_clf_lsvc = Pipeline([('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()),('svd', TruncatedSVD()),
                     ('clf', LinearSVC()),])
predictions = text_clf_lsvc.predict(X_test)
```

my metrci acuuracy score dropped to 34%.

***my questions:***

1- How can I improve my model if I want to stick to TF-IDF and SVC for classification
2- What can I do other than that if I want to have a good classification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to improve accuracy, given that you want to stick with this configuration is through *hyperparameter* tuning, or by introducing additional components, such as *feature selection*.

**Hyperparameter tuning**

Most machine learning algorithms and parts of a machine learning pipeline have several parameters you can change. For example, the `TfidfVectorizer` has different ngram ranges, different analysis levels, different tokenizers, and many more parameters to vary. Most of these will affect your performance. So, what you can do is systematically vary these parameters (and those of your `SVC`), while monitoring you accuracy on a *development set* (i.e., **not the test data!**). Instead of fixed development set, cross-validation is typically used in these kinds of settings.

The best way to do this in `sklearn` is through a `RandomizedSearchCV` (see [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html) for details). This class automatically cross-validates and searches through the possible options you pre-specify by randomly sampling from the option set for a fixed number of iterations. By applying this technique on your training data, you will automatically find models that perform better for your given training data and your options. Ideally, these models would also perform better on your test data. Fair warning: cross-validated search techniques can take a while to run.

**Feature Selection**

In addition to grid search, another way to improve performance is through *feature selection*. Feature selection typically consists of a statistical test that determines which features explain variance in the typical task you are trying to solve. The feature selection methods in `sklearn` are detailed [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html#feature-selection).

By far the most important bit here is that the performance of anything you add to your model should be verified on an independent development set, or in cross-validation. Leave your test data alone.

Comment: thank you so much for the clear explanation and helpful links